# Notify Button of DataBind change

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have databound this property to a button as shown below, how do I notify the button when the other boolean properties have updated in order to check this again?

### DataBinding Property

```
public bool AccountSelectedAndBankFileSelected
{
    get
    {
        return SelectedAccount != null && SelectedAccount.BankFileSelected;
    }
}
```

### Button

```
<Button Content="Open bank." IsEnabled="{Binding AccountSelectedAndBankFileSelected}" />
```

### BankFileSelected Property

```
public bool BankFileSelected
{
    get { return _bankFileSelected; }
    set { _bankFileSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("BankFileSelected"); }
}
```

Comment: Show the setter for `SelectedAccount.BankFileSelected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices. You can either change the `AccountSelectedAndBankFileSelected` to a dependency property, or you can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The second may be the easiest. What you do is you implement this interface. Then, when any of the properties that decide the result of `AccountSelectedAndBankFileSelected` changes (so the `SelectedAccount` and `SelectedAccount.BankFileSelected` properties), you raise the event that the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface defines.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I already have the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implemented. The two other properties have events raised when they are changed, but for some reason the Button still isn't notified.

Comment: Do you trigger the event when both the `SelectedAccount` and the `SelectedAccount.BankFileSelected` properties change?

Answer (score 1):

The `View` doesn't know whether the property was changed or not.
You should call `RaisePropertyChanged("AccountSelectedAndBankFileSelected")` (or `NotifyPropertyChanged("AccountSelectedAndBankFileSelected")`) in `SelectedAccount.BankFileSelected` setter:

```
    public bool BankFileSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return bankFileSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            bankFileSelected= value;
            yourViewModel.RaisePropertyChanged("AccountSelectedAndBankFileSelected");
        }
    }
```